# Conditional expectation and inequality

Tags: conditional-expectation

This should be relatively easy question but my math skills are rather limited.

Assume a that i is uniformly distributed between $\ [0,3] $

Also, assume that there is a price such that:

$$p \ge E[v * i | w * i \le p]$$

v and w are two unknown parameter with $\ w \gt v $. How do I calculate the conditional expectation of this formula, and how I handle the fact that the price parameter conditions i?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: just did thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $w,v$ are deterministic and for simplicity both $w,v>0$.

If $I \sim U(0,3)$, then $vI \sim U(0,3v)$ and $P(vI|wI \leq p) \sim U(0,\frac{vp}{w})$. Therefore $$\mathrm E[vI|wI \leq p] = \frac{vp}{2w}.$$ 
From this you can see the contidition under which such $p$ exists.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer the question, but I am still confused about the general approach you took here. Sorry.

Comment: Can you derive distribution of $vI $ and then  use the Bayes' theorem to derive the  distribution of $P(vI|wI \leq p)$ ?

Comment: No, I can't. I am sorry.

Comment: Actually just got it

Comment: @user1738753 wonderful, glad to help!